# How do I stop requestAnimationFrame

Tags: three.js

I need to remove a canvas and build a new one. I'm having a problem where I don't know how to stop/interrupt the Three.js or webGL update process. I can stop it if I force a javascript error (but that's really stupid).

Does anyone know how to stop the process so that I don't start to pile processes that aren't doing anything useful or conflicting with the new ones?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
var id;

function animate() {

    id = requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

To cancel

```
cancelAnimationFrame( id );
```

three.js r.55

Comment: thanks it works. i just had to look for where and how to save that id because i'm using another "framework" on top of three.js