# How to turn off animation in three.js

Tags: three.js

While testing code in three.js, animation is not needed.  I can see the first rendered frame.  This would use less power, and stop the fan on the laptop from kicking in as the graphics card heats up.

The examples in three.js have the following structure:

```
function init() {
  animate()
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
    targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown + ( mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.05;
}

function render() {
    group.rotation.y += ( targetRotation - group.rotation.y ) * 0.05;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

I do not see how to turn off the repeated calls to animate.
Is there any easy way to turn off animation?

Comment: As a quick hack, just comment out `requestAnimationFrame( animate );` or see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465495/how-do-i-stop-requestanimationframe/14466255#14466255).

Comment: When you comment out requestAnimationFrame, the window never refreshes.

Comment: Actually, it seems like ti's working now.  Refresh problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to have an animation loop in three.js -- say, if you have a static scene. Just call

```
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

You will need to re-render whenever the camera moves or when loaders finish loading models or loading textures.

If you are using `OrbitControls` with a static scene, you can instantiate `OrbitControls` like so:

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // use if there is no animation loop
```

where `render()` calls `renderer.render( scene, camera )`.

If you are loading models or textures, the three.js loaders have a callback function you can specify. For example,

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = loader.load( 'myTexture.jpg', render );
```

Also

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );

loader.load( 'myModel.obj', function( object ) {
    // your code...
    render();
}
```

three.js r.75